# How can I get data inside of completionHandler for Alamofire.responseJSon

Tags: swift, alamofire, completionhandler

I'm currently making app for Destiny 2 API.

and I'm struggling with this issue

this is my whole function code that makes hash data to item name

I want to return that name variable which is guarded last, but that completion handler

runs after function is end.

I searched to internet, but almost everyone just used this data inside of it, not

function return.

that I only need is " Parse json and get returned data I want "

is there any idea please?

item parameter means " item hash to get name of it "
lang parameter means " language to return " if this is "en" then, it should return English.
here's the data I pared too " https://pastebin.com/1tV6fx9F "

```
func hashToName(item: String, lang: String = "ko") (" want to return String "-> String ){
    let url = String(format: "https://www.bungie.net/platform/Destiny2/Manifest/DestinyInventoryItemDefinition/\(item)")
    let param: [String: String] = ["lc": "\(lang)"]
    let head: HTTPHeaders = ["x-api-key": "b21e4d2d33234b82be6e56893554974b"]
    
    
    let doNetwork = AF.request(url, method:.get, parameters: param, encoder: URLEncodedFormParameterEncoder.default, headers: head)
    doNetwork.responseJSON {
        response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let site):
            guard let dict = site as? NSDictionary else { return }
            guard let res = dict["Response"] as? NSDictionary else { return }
            guard let prop = res["displayProperties"] as? NSDictionary else { return }
            guard let name: String = prop["name"] as? String else { return }
            
            print(name) // data I want to return
        case .failure(let err):
            print(err.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    func hashToName(item: String, lang: String = "ko", returnString: @escaping (String)->()) {
        let url = String(format: "https://www.bungie.net/platform/Destiny2/Manifest/DestinyInventoryItemDefinition/\(item)")
        let param: [String: String] = ["lc": "\(lang)"]
        let head: HTTPHeaders = ["x-api-key": "b21e4d2d33234b82be6e56893554974b"]
        
        
        let doNetwork = AF.request(url, method:.get, parameters: param, encoder: URLEncodedFormParameterEncoder.default, headers: head)
        doNetwork.responseJSON {
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let site):
                guard let dict = site as? NSDictionary else { return }
                guard let res = dict["Response"] as? NSDictionary else { return }
                guard let prop = res["displayProperties"] as? NSDictionary else { return }
                guard let name: String = prop["name"] as? String else { return }
                returnString(name)
                print(name) // data I want to return
            case .failure(let err):
                print(err.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }

//How to use
hashToName(item: "Your string") { str in
            print(str)
        }
```